# how to auto save in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, autosave

Hi I am working on web application using Angularjs. Currently I have a feature to save the data entered by the user.By clicking on the save button we are sending some data through service call Now there was change in the requirement. The data needs to save automatically when ever we crawl to next page or of session ended. Is there any way make service call automatically. I thought of with setInterval but that is not the correct way I think. Kindly suggest some better way of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In case of page movement, save it when the controller is destroyed

```
   $scope.$on('$destroy', function something() {
        yourService.save();
    });
```